# Removing subarrays from multidimensional array by value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this [API](http://backpack.tf/api/prices), which provides an array that looks as follows:

```
[Air Strike] => Array
    (
        [defindex] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1104
            )

        [prices] => Array
            (
                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [Tradable] => Array
                            (
                                [Craftable] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [currency] => metal
                                                [value] => 0.05
                                                [last_update] => 1415072318
                                                [difference] => -0.06
                                                [value_raw] => 0.05
                                            )

                                    )

                                [Non-Craftable] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [currency] => metal
                                                [value] => 0.11
                                                [last_update] => 1436478504
                                                [difference] => 0.03
                                                [value_raw] => 0.11
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [Tradable] => Array
                            (
                                [Craftable] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [currency] => metal
                                                [value] => 4
                                                [last_update] => 1456277271
                                                [difference] => -0.165
                                                [value_raw] => 4
                                            )

                                    )

                                [Non-Craftable] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [currency] => metal
                                                [value] => 3.66
                                                [last_update] => 1456277553
                                                [difference] => -0.34
                                                [value_raw] => 3.66
                                            )                  

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Is there any way I can remove subarrays at the point where they, for lack of a better word, diverge if the item is either untradable or ['value_raw'] is less than 3?

My desired output would be this:

```
[Air Strike] => Array
(
    [defindex] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1104
        )

    [prices] => Array
        (
           [11] => Array
                (
                    [Tradable] => Array
                        (
                            [Craftable] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => metal
                                            [value] => 4
                                            [last_update] => 1456277271
                                            [difference] => -0.165
                                            [value_raw] => 4
                                        )

                                )

                            [Non-Craftable] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => metal
                                            [value] => 3.66
                                            [last_update] => 1456277553
                                            [difference] => -0.34
                                            [value_raw] => 3.66
                                        )                  

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My thoughts on this have been to iterate over every subarray with a nested foreach() loop and check the value of ['value_raw'] and whether or not it's tradable, but then how would I know how many subarrays to remove without removing too much? Perhaps going backwards starting at the priceindex and then checking whether it contains more than one subarray and if it doesn't remove it together with all its contents?

Comment: just use a `foreach` then `unset` based on your criteria using those keys

Comment: @Ghost I have tried doing `unset(array['prices'])` in a nested foreach loop but it didn't have the desired effect

Comment: In your desired output last element has ['value_raw'] < 4

Comment: @fusion3k you are correct. thanks for pointing out that mistake. I edited my post to match the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain desired result through a series of nested `foreach()` loop:

```
foreach( $airStrike['prices'] as $gKey => $group )
{
    foreach( $group as $sKey => $subGroup )
    {
        if( $sKey !== 'Tradable' ) unset( $airStrike['prices'][$gKey][$sKey] );
        else
        {
            foreach( $subGroup as $iKey => $item )
            {
                if( $item[0]['value_raw'] < 3 ) unset( $airStrike['prices'][$gKey][$sKey][$iKey] );
            }

            if( !count( $airStrike['prices'][$gKey][$sKey] ) ) unset( $airStrike['prices'][$gKey][$sKey] );
        }
        if( !count( $airStrike['prices'][$gKey] ) ) unset( $airStrike['prices'][$gKey] );
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/inNBR)**</kbd>

Items with key ≠ 'Tradable' are unset. 'Tradable' sub-items are processed and, if 'value_raw' is < 3, are unset. Referring to your example, 'Craftable' and 'Non-Craftable' sub-arrays are considered with **only one** child array: if they can have more than one child, you have to add an additional `foreach()` iside `foreach( $subGroup )`.

Note that at the end of level-2 and level-3 `foreach()` I check if the current array is empty and — if it is — I unset it.